# What would a prison on a space station or huge ship in Lower Earth Orbit be Called?

Tags: science-fiction, space-travel, spaceships

What would the proper term be for the Brig/Prison/Jail where someone gets thrown for a crime on a giant space station or ship? Any idea what the interrogation room for such a ship would be called (if there is another name for one)?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You seem to already have a set of tradition based names, and asking us for additional names is just  a matter of polling on our personal tastes and preferences, which is not the type of question fitting our standards.

Comment: The question specifies 'proper term' rather than our opinions or a list of plausible synonyms.

Comment: Hi Valetta! We're delighted to have you join us on [worldbuilding.se]. Let me help you understand why this question was closed. Our [help/dont-ask] states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where ... your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers and every answer is equally valid." @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica is right in that you provided your answer, but you're also right in that it's really not that simple. That brings us to the second condition I mentioned, "equally valid." (\*continued\*)

Comment: No matter what anyone says, you asked a question where every answer is equally valid because (a) we don't have space-faring vehicles large enough to employ rooms for imprisonment and (b) Ultimately, the choice to use naval tradition over land-lubber tradition is your choice, a fancy way of saying "story based," which is actually another reason to close questions. What if your spacecraft were large enough to justify a civilian authority? That might imply "jail" is best. Only military? maybe "brig" is best. But here's the real problem: what if you choose something (\*continued\*)

Comment: *simply because it gave your story flavor, a different twist, by inviting readers to enjoy a culture they haven't encountered before?* Can you see our problem? Factually (and I mean that, "factually") there is no right answer because the only useful answer can only address your preference for story writing, which we call "storybuilding," which is off-topic here. Worldbuilding is about developing and consistently using the rules and systems for a fictional world of your own creation wherein an infinite number of stories can be told. The names of things are window dressing for your world.

Answer (score 3):

Brig is a term used by U.S. Naval personel and derivitive military services (U.S. Coast Guard and U.S. Marines) and is derrived from the word Brigantine, which was a sailing ship with two square rigged masts and abriviated as "Brig".   While this was a classification of ships in the age of sail, in the early U.S. Navy these ships were frequently used as prison ships over war ships.   It should also be noted, that in North American English, the term "prison" and "jail" do have different meanings (A "jail" is used to hold pre-trial accused and convicted misdomenor offenders (1 year of dentention punishment or less) while a Prison holds convicted Felony offenders (sentanced to over a year of dentention punishment)) though most people will use "Jail" and "Prison" interchangebly.   In a legal sense, they are distinct and partially denote the security of the facility.

The Modern U.S. Navy has three levels of facilities for offenders.  Level one is the lowest and includes Waterfront Brigs (a jail at a US Naval Station), Afloat Brigs (jails in ships), Correction Custody Units (CCUs not sure what the difference is) and Pre-Trial Confinement Facilities.  All of these are for pre-trial detention OR detention punishment with less than a year time.    Level 2 is for Offenders who have less than 10 years and are one of two "Consolidated Brigs" which are permanent structures.   Finally level 3 are U.S.  disciplinary barracks (which hold offenders from all service branches).

It may also be of interest to look into naming conventions for ground based military prison facilities as while fiction usally has space ships using navel terms (Captain is senior most officer, port and starboard directions, ect) in all likely-hood space based military will use Army terms, considering that U.S. Space Command is an offshoot Branch of the U.S. Airforce which itself is an offshoot Branch of the U.S. Army (Where as USN and USCG both were independently formed, while the Marines are the "Navy's Ground fighting force" though these days their more of the combined arms service (having elements of Land, Sea, and Air combat forces) and use Navy personel for support roles (there is no Marine Doctor or Chaplain service, but rather these roles are filled by Navy personel who take postings with the Marines).   Thus, realisitically Space Forces will spawn from air combat cultures (though both Airforce pilots and Naval Aviators both were counted among the first U.S. Astronauts).  There is some limited searching for terms as back in the Zepplin days, the U.S. Army Air Corps (the proto Airforce) did man the Zepplin fleets, which were the closest things to flying naval ship sized vessels we have to date.

It should also be pointed out that the BSG used some wonky rank structures in the 2004 remake.   The enlisted ranks are all naval enlisted ranks while the Officer Ranks go from Naval (Ensign, Lieutenant Junior Grade (LTJG), Lieutenant) followed by two Army ranks (Captain (which IRL is the same rank as a Naval Lieutenant), Major) than goes to full Colonel (XO) then Full Commander (CO) and the flag ranks are Admirals (In real militaries, a Full Colonel is equivelent to a Naval Captain, while a Lt. Colonel is equivelent to a full Commander.).

Finally, a special note, since BSG is kind of a space carrier, in the Modern U.S. Navy, Carriers are an exception to the general rule that "Every Ship Must have only One Captain).   U.S. Carriers have two Captains:  The Ships's Captain and the Ship's CAG.   Both hold the rank of Naval Captain, but the ship's Captain is in charge of surface opperations while the CAG is in charge of Air Operations.   Thus launching a plane from the carrier deck is  the CAG's job, but in order for him to get the Carrier to turn to face the right direction for proper wind speeds, he has to ask the ship Captain to give the order... if they don't agree, they have to go to the Rear Admiral (Lower Half) on board to bark the orders (An Admiral on a Capital Ship is nothing new... much of modern Naval Warfare relies on the Capital Ship being surrounded by a protective screen and this was common back when Battle Ship theory was predominant.   The Admiral on the Capital ship is in charge of all the ships in the protective screen plus the capital ship (Known as a Group and usually further divided by type of Capital Ship:  Battleship Group or Carrier Group).

In most other navys with a Carrier, the CAG is a senior officer but Junior to the Captain.  U.S. Carriers are massive by comparison... and they have more Carriers than the rest of the world's navies combined (and that's before you add the U.S.'s Amphibious Assault ships, which are roughly on the size of a standard non-U.S. Carrier).

Comment: One of the better examples of why this question was closed is the etymology of the word "brig." The word comes from "brigantine," derived first from the Italian and then the French, for a two-masted vessel, which sometimes were used as prison ships before decomissioning. The word has the same root as "brigand," a type of pirate. The English-speaking world is therefore using a word in the context of, "send the pirate to the French!" It was intended to be insulting, not just a synonym for "jail," which all underscores why questions asking for names are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

There is some history to idea that once words are used for a particular purpose they stick. For example. I believe that the term "to scrub" a mission is still used in the US Airforce or was until relatively recently. This came from the RAF during world war 2. The RAF inherited the term from the Royal Flying Corps during world war 1. In those days missions details for times, targets and crews were chalked up on a large blackboard. If bad weather prevented the mission it was literally scrubbed off the board.

I see no reason why the Brig should not remain the Brig in your world as the term could easily be carried forward for a long time.

Comment: American space launch organizations (such as SpaceX, for example) routinely use the verb "to scrub" with the meaning of abandoning a launch attempt for various reasons, usually with a view of retrying it later.

Comment: The phrase lives on

Answer (score 0):

Jail

Brig is an American only term, that dates back to the time of prison ships and refers to the type of ship most commonly used. So you have to ask yourself, is your ship American. If so Brig is fine, if not, Jail is the word you want.

Prison is an entire building/institution so thats right out. Jail is the most universal term for what you want, it refers to a place for the confinement of people accused or convicted of a crime.

According to [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jail)

Jail: a place of confinement for persons held in lawful custody
specifically : such a place under the jurisdiction of a local government (such as a county) for the confinement of persons awaiting trial or those convicted of minor crimes

Brig: a place (as on a ship) for temporary confinement of offenders in the U.S. Navy

Comment: *Brig* is an American-only term, and *jail* is an American-only spelling -- elsewhere it's *gaol*. The distinction between jail and prison is also American-only -- elsewhere persons under arrest or temporary custody awaiting trial are not kept in penal institutions, and persons convicted for lesser infractions are kept in the same institutions as persons convicted for more serious infractions.

Comment: @alex you would be wrong, remand exists in many countries including the UK and Sweden and just like the US it is not always used but tends to be reserved for more serous crimes. also according ot Wiki (for what it is worth) Gaol is being replaced by jail in many places so in the future you should only see the use of jail. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gaol#Usage_notes

Comment: Thank you -- spelling lesson noted. But I still cannot think of any country other than the USA which have places of imprisonment under the power of local authorities. In Europe it would be very strange for a city or county to have power to imprison people.